# how to set value from datepicker in d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

    <title>D3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle1.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
 </head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script>
    //for datepicker 
    function processData(f1, f2){
    var v1= document.getElementById(f1).value.toString();
    var v2= document.getElementById(f2).value.toString();
    alert (v1+"\n"+v2);
    return v1, v2;
    valPicker1=v1;   //passed values that were attained above in valpickr1 and pickr2
     valPicker2=v2;
    }
        var myData = [100, 125, 320, 440];
        var height = 300;
        var width = 500;

        var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
            .style('position', 'absolute')
            .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
            .style('padding', '5 15px')
            .style('border', '1px #333 solid')
            .style('border-radius', '5px')
            .style('opacity', 'o')


        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(myData)])
            .range([0, height]);
        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d3.range(0, myData.length))
            .rangeBands([0, width])
        var colors = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, myData.length])
            .range(['#90ee90', '#30c230'])
        d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
            .selectAll('rect')
            .data(myData)
            .enter().append('rect')
            .style('fill', function (d, i) {
                return colors(i);
            })
            .attr('width', xScale.rangeBand())
            .attr('height', function (d) {
                return yScale(d);
            })
            .attr('x', function (d, i) {
                return xScale(i);
            })
            .attr('y', function (d) {
                return height - yScale(d);
            })
            .on('mouseover', function (d) {
                tooltip.transition()
                    .style('opacity', 1)

                tooltip.html(d)
                    .style('left', (d3.event.pageX) + 'px')
                    .style('top', (d3.event.pagey) + 'px')
                d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.5)
            })
            .on('mouseout', function (d) {
                tooltip.transition()
                    .style('opacity', 0)
                d3.select(this).style('opacity', 1)
            })

        var vScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(myData)])
            .range([height, 0]);
        var hScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d3.range(0, myData.length))
            .rangeBands([0, width])

        //vaxis
        var vAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(vScale)
            .orient('left')
            //v guide
        var vGuide = d3.select('svg')
            .append('g')
        vAxis(vGuide)
        vGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(35,10)')
        vGuide.selectAll('path')
            .style('fill', 'none')
            .style('stroke', '#000')
        vGuide.selectAll('line')
            .style('stroke', '#000')

        //Haxis
        var hAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(hScale)
            .orient('bottom')
            //H guide
        var hGuide = d3.select('svg')
            .append('g')
        hAxis(hGuide)
        hGuide.attr('transform', 'translate(35,' + (height - 25) + ')')
        hGuide.selectAll('path')
            .style('fill', 'none')
            .style('stroke', '#000')
        hGuide.selectAll('line')
            .style('stroke', '#000')
    </script>

    <div align ="center">
From : <input type="date" name="field1" id="field1" />
To :   <input type="date" name="field2" id="field2" /><br /><br />
<input type="button" onclick="processData('field1','field2')" value="Submit" />

</div>





</body>
<html>
```

I want to get values from my 2 datepickers which are on my web page so user can select values at runtime from those 2datepicekrs i.e to: and from : only two values of date that should be displayed on `x axis`  but I don't know how should I bind those values form date pickers to my `x-axis`. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to set the domain as array of dates you want to display for your x-axis. and you can re-render the chart when you select dates.

Check the below code if it helps -

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

        <title>D3</title>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle1.css" /> -->

        <style>

         body {
          color: #000;
         }

   .axis {
     font: 10px sans-serif;
   }

   .axis path,
   .axis line {
     fill: none;
     stroke: #000;
     shape-rendering: crispEdges;
   }

   .bar {
    fill: steelblue;
   }

   .bar:hover {
    fill: brown;
   }

  </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
     </head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div id="chart"></div>
        <div align ="center">
   From : <input type="date" name="field1" id="field1" />
   To :   <input type="date" name="field2" id="field2" /><br /><br />
   <input type="button" onclick="render(true)" value="Submit" />
  </div>

        <script>

         var myData = [
          { value: 100, date: '2016-01-01'},
    { value: 125, date: '2016-02-02'},
    { value: 320, date: '2016-03-03'},
      { value: 440, date: '2016-04-04'}
     ];

     var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

     var margin  = { top: 20, right: 0, bottom: 80, left: 40 };
     var width  = 500 - margin.left - margin.right;
      var height  = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var xScale  = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
            var yScale  = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
            var hAxis  = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom').tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"));
            var vAxis  = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left');
            var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
                   .style('position', 'absolute')
                   .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
                   .style('padding', '5 15px')
                   .style('border', '1px #333 solid')
                   .style('border-radius', '5px')
                   .style('opacity', 'o');

   myData.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date  = parseDate(d.date);
    d.value = +d.value;
   });

         function getDates() {
          return [document.getElementById('field1').value, document.getElementById('field2').value];
         }

   function render(filterByDates) {

    d3.select('svg').remove();

    if(filterByDates) {
     var date1 = parseDate(document.getElementById('field1').value);
     var date2 = parseDate(document.getElementById('field2').value);

     myData = myData.filter(function(d) {
      return d.date >= date1 && d.date <= date2;
     });
    }

    xScale.domain(myData.map(function(d) { 
     return d.date; 
    }));
    
    yScale.domain([0, d3.max(myData, function (d) { return d.value; })]);

    var svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
             
             svg
                 .append('g')
        .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                 .call(hAxis)
                 .selectAll("text")
     .style("text-anchor", "end")
     .attr("dx", "-.8em")
     .attr("dy", "-.55em")
     .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

             svg
              .append('g')
                 .attr("class", "y axis")
                 // .attr('transform', 'translate(35,' + (height - 25) + ')')
                 .call(vAxis)

    svg
     .selectAll(".bar")
     .data(myData)
     .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("class", "bar")
     .style("fill", "steelblue")
     .attr("x", function(d) { 
      return xScale(d.date); 
     })
     .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
     .attr("y", function(d) { 
      return yScale(d.value); 
     })
     .attr("height", function(d) { 
      return height - yScale(d.value); 
     })
     .on('mouseover', function (d) {
                     tooltip.transition()
                         .style('opacity', 1)

                     tooltip.html(d.value)
                         .style('left', (d3.event.pageX) + 'px')
                         .style('top', (d3.event.pagey) + 'px')
                     d3.select(this).style('opacity', 0.5)
                 })
                 .on('mouseout', function (d) {
                     tooltip.transition()
                         .style('opacity', 0)
                     d3.select(this).style('opacity', 1)
                 });
   }

            render(false);

        </script>
  
 </body>
<html>
```